# How to handle list - 5000 DropdownMenuItem?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have list with strings - about 5k positions. I need to convert this list to List< DropdownMenuItem> and I use this in SearchableDropdown.

How to do this most effectively? Or how to do this once when I start the app and save somewhere?

Now I have lag about 3-5 sec when it's loading every time when I open one screen. And I can't use others SearchableDropdown because the have lags to when this big list is loading :/

```
  @override
  void initState() {
convert(BIG_LIST).then((value){
      list.addAll(value);
    });
}


Future<List<DropdownMenuItem>> convert(List<String> BIG_LIST) async {
    List<DropdownMenuItem> results = [];
    await Future.forEach(BIG_LIST, (string){
      results(DropdownMenuItem(
        child: Text(string),
        value: string,
      ));
    });
    return results;
  }


Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.6,
                      child: SearchableDropdown(
                        items: list,
                        isExpanded: true,
                        value: value,
                        hint: new Text('Select'),
                        searchHint: new Text(
                          'Select',
                          style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                        ),
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          print(value);
                          setState(() {
                            text = value;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
```

Comment: If you're loading 5k items into a single dropdown, you probably need to rethink your UX...

Comment: None of your users will be happy to have to choice from **5000** items in a dropdown! That's just ***waaaaaaay too many** items for a dropdown - 10, 20 - maybe - 100 at absolute most - but 5000 ?!?!?!

Comment: @marc_s ok but I have textfield for search in this 5000 items. It's bad?

Comment: Dropdown is a bad option, if you really want to have such a long list and want to make it searchable use ListView.builder. it will create list items lazily and will not hang your UI. you can hide/show your List using button or some dialog.